# I'm using mesibo Chat SDK, when I am trying to show notification on (onMessage) implemented function of mesibo message listener interface

Tags: android, kotlin, chat, mesibo

```
override fun Mesibo_onMessage(p0: Mesibo.MessageParams?, p1: ByteArray?): Boolean {
if (userManager.isLogged()) {
  Timber.d(" on message : %s", p0?.profile?.name)
  Timber.d(" on message : %s", p0?.profile?.address)
  p0?.profile?.name?.let { sendNotification(it, String(p1!!, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), applicationContext) }
}
return true
```

}

**I'm uisng this code to show notification after receiving messages, I don't know why the profile name return the address of user not his name

**

**I'm using this code to setup mesibo and setting my profile and it did not work also give me user address in message params profile name**

```
private fun setupMesibo() {
val user = UserManager.getInstance().getUser()
if (UserManager.getInstance().isLogged()) {
  Mesibo.getInstance().init(this)
  Mesibo.addListener(this)
  Mesibo.setRestartListener(this)
  Mesibo.setSecureConnection(true)
  Mesibo.setAccessToken(user?.mesiboToken)
  val myProfile = UserProfile()
  myProfile.name = userManager.getUser()?.name
  myProfile.address = userManager.getUser()?.mesiboAddress
  Mesibo.setSelfProfile(myProfile)
  Mesibo.setUserProfile(myProfile, true)
  Mesibo.setDatabase("mydb", 0)
  MesiboCall.getInstance().init(applicationContext)
  Mesibo.setAppInForeground(this, 0, true)
  Mesibo.start()
  Mesibo.setPushToken(TokenManager.getInstance().getFCMToken())
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

mesibo does not know the name unless you set it using user profile APIs. In such cases, it sets the name as the address. You should use mesibo user profile APIs to set the profile for address and save.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/real-time-api/profiles/

> A profile allows you to associate human readable information such as
> name, picture, status, presence information, etc. with a user or a
> group.

Comment: i'm using setSelfProfile method but dose not work

Comment: You should be using setProfile. You may also refer to the messenger source code to know how it is used.

Comment: I'm using the above code to setup mesibo @Mark

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Your code is wrong, asked you to use setUserProfile for each user and group, and not setSelfProfile.

Comment: I have read the documentation but still same issue

Comment: I removed setSelfProfile  and  used setUserProfile9

Comment: For every user and group, you should do the same. whatever you set there, you will get it when you receive a message from that address.

Comment: for every user after setup mesibo i creat instance from UserProfile and set it to the current user but the user name comes as user address in messageParams.profile.name
 I don't know what to do else